# Payday 2 anarchist and crew chief

Tags: payday-2

I was wondering if the anarchist and crew chief stacks with each other. It says like 50% of your health is combined into 110% armor bla bla... so does this mean if one of your teammates uses the crew chief skill deck, does this make the anarchist gain more armor? or how does it work? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What the anarchist perk deck does is it takes your HP stat and cuts it in half. Meaning, you have less raw HP.

On the other hand, it takes your armour stat and boosts it by 110 points (as far as I can tell using a suit. It may vary by the armour you use but thats how it worked for me)

Comment: This does not exactly answer if and how other hp buffs like the one from crew chief factor into anarchist.

Answer (score 1):

Any maximum health boosts you get are factored into how much armor you get from Anarchist, including health boosts from Crew Chief. You can actually get even more massive boosts from Partners in Crime aced since having a converted enemy gives you 30% more health.

Straight from [The Long Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=267214370):

> Likewise, with the Anarchist perk deck, Partner in Crime aced and a converted enemy, ICTV and a Crew Chief teammate as well as 10 or more hostages, the maximum armor value is (170 + 230*1.2*(0.5+0.1+0.3+0.02*10)) * (1+0.05+0.3) = 639. But the inventory will never tell you because some bonuses are situational.

This is how much you can get out of Partners in Crime aced:

> +x armor, where x = (1.2 * health). Typically, this means 230*0.5*1.2 = +138 armor. Health bonuses help a lot, e.g. with Partners in Crime aced, you have 230*0.8*1.2 = +220.8 armor instead.